# hide and show div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I'm trying to implement a switch/tracker to my HTML5 game.
A short description of what I want jQuery to do for me: hide all `div` tags and show the ones I need (body, output, language, footer and a specific level f.i. `Level 1` Once this has been shown, it needs to show the next level f.i. `Level 2` on clicking a bottom.

But I don't know how to code this. So can anyone please help me?
 
So far I have written this:

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    function hideshow() {
        $("div").hide(99999999);
        $("#container").show(9999999);
        $(".output").show(9999999);
        $("#languages").show(9999999);
        $("footer").show(999999);
        $("#L1").show(999999);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better practice to hide the div's with css, or even replacing the `Level 1` with `Level 2` content (ajax based for example).

If you cannot do that, give all level div's a class, and only hide those with

```
$('.level').hide(); $('#level1').show();
```

The way to make a function show something is to do

```
$('#level2').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery css method:

---

```
$("div").css("display", "none"); //for hiding
$("div").css("display", "block"); //for displaying
```